# Android Organise overlapping views?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a RelativeLayout which has 4 LinearLayouts (that are overlapping one another). Is there a way for me to better organise them? I mean create a separate xml for each and them link all the xml's back to the container?

Im not sure if ViewPager is the right way to go, because in the code im animating the Alpha value of these views, and need all of them to be while the Activity runs.

For now the main activity is pretty simple, but later on Im gonna be adding a few TextViews/EditTexts etc, so its gonna get really confusing to manage it all.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/details_pure_white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/details_pure_green"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_pure_white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#28bda9" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2b"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/settings_pure_green"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textColor="#FFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Okay, just found an option in the Palette that allows you to add other XMLs statically. Will update if its a solution

Answer (score 0):

Used this thing called `<include>`

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/ref_details_green_activity" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/ref_details_white_activity" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/ref_settings_green_activity" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/ref_settings_white_activity" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```